# Ember and RESTadapter: when is JSON call executed?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When using the Ember RESTadapter, at what moments are JSON calls executed ?

**Example 1:**

- If I goto /index.html#/articles/, a JSON call to resource articles is executed.
- When I then browse to /index.html#/articles/2, no additional call is executed.
- I was expecting a call to the individual article via JSON.

**Example 2:**

- When after application load, I go immediately to /index.html#/articles/1, 2 JSON calls are executed: one to articles and one to articles/1.
- However, when looping over the articles collection (with #each), only article 1 is completed with data.
- Why are 2 calls done and why is only the data of one article loaded ?

**My routes:**

```
App.ArticlesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return App.Article.find();
  }
});

App.ArticlesShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    return App.Article.find(params.article_id);
  }
});
```

Hope somebody can give me basic explanation or a link to additional help.

Many thanks
Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I goto /index.html#/articles/, a JSON call to resource articles is executed.

This is correct because the adapter will fetch all the articles.

> When I then browse to /index.html#/articles/2, no additional call is executed.

This is also correct since the articles are already in the store and will be served from there.

Your respective router map should look like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('articles', function() {
    this.route('show', {path: '/show/:article_id'});
  })
});
```

This will make your `ArticlesShowRoute` obsolete since it is the default behavior. You only need to define explicitly your `ArticlesShowRoute` if you want something different than the default behavior.

> When after application load, I go immediately to /index.html#/articles/1, 2 JSON calls are executed: one to articles and one to articles/1.

This might be redundant...

> However, when looping over the articles collection (with #each), only article 1 is completed with data.

At this point you should be able to loop over your articles collection and link to the respective article to be shown:

```
{{#each article in model}}
  {{#linkTo 'articles.show' article}}Show article{{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. What behaviour would you expect if you browse immediately to route articles/show/2 ?  Will then only article 2 be loaded (thus calling articlkes/2 via JSON request) or will all articles be loaded (thus calling JSON request articles).

Comment: @Marc, the behaviour I would expect when browsing to route `articles/2` directly would be that all articles would be loaded and then article/2 should be served from the store, but I'm not really sure why the are instead to calls, one to articles and one for the extra article with id 2

Comment: Thanks.  I will do some further tests and try to document in more detail the behavior.